# Signed apk file

Tags: android, apk

I have an app released on the Google Play store. I have the signed apk file which is the same one I have published to the store. If I emailed this apk file to to someone, could they publish this app as thier own? Not only on the play store but Amazon store as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've uploaded your app to the Google Play Store, no, they cannot upload this app to the Play Store and overwrite yours. Only one listing per application ID is allowed.

They can upload it to the Amazon App Store, and you will be unable to upload/update your app on the Amazon App Store unless you change your application ID (as set in your `build.gradle`). This will result in an additional listing which you control - they will control and update the other listing, but as they probably don't have your source code nor your signing key, they won't be able to update it in any legitimate way.